# Why didn't the author write as follows in his proof? (Theorem 18.2 on p.154 in "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question, diffeomorphism

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

> **Theorem 18.2.** Let $g:A\to B$ be a diffeomorphism of class $C^r,$  where $A$ and $B$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Let $D$ be a compact subset of $A,$ and let $E=g(D).$
> (a) We have $g(\operatorname{Int}D)=\operatorname{Int}E$ and $g(\operatorname{Bd}D)=\operatorname{Bd}E.$
> (b) If $D$ is rectifiable, so is $E.$
> These results also hold when $D$ is not compact, provided $\operatorname{Bd}D\subset A$ and $\operatorname{Bd}E\subset B.$

> Proof. (a) The map $g^{-1}$ is continuous. Therefore, for any open set $U$ contained in $A,$ the set $g(U)$ is an open set contained in $B.$

Of course, the author's proof of this part is right.
But the author wrote the following theorem on p.65.

> **Theorem 8.2.** Let $A$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n;$ let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^r;$ let $B=f(A).$ If $f$ is one-to-one on $A$ and if $Df(x)$ is non-singular for $x\in A,$ then the set $B$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the inverse function $g:B\to A$ is of class $C^r.$

Let $U$ be an open set contained in $A.$
Then $g:U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is of class $C^r.$
$g$ is one-to-one on $U.$
$Dg(x)$ is non-singular for $x\in U$.
So, by Theorem 8.2, $g(U)$ is an open set contained in $B$.

The author didn't write as follows.
Why?

> Proof. (a) By Theorem 8.2, for any open set $U$ contained in $A,$ the set $g(U)$ is an open set contained in $B.$

Comment: I can't, obviously, know why someone chooses a particular order to lay down theorems. However, it seems to me that Th.8.2 serves one purpose: *outline sufficient conditions for a smooth map to be a diffeomorphism*, while Th. 18.2 is part of *a map is a diffeomorphism already - what does it mean?* - in particular *a diffeomorphism is a homeomorphism*. I feel like, for a given map $f$, Th 8.2 can tell us if $f$ is a diffeomorphism, and then, *knowing* that $f$ is a diffeomorphism, Th 18.2 tells us that it is also a homeomorphism, with some topological insight coming from that. ... (TBC)

Comment: (Cont'd) ... as well. Thus, it doesn't make sense to use Th 8.2 in the proof of Th 18.2: with Th 18.2 we already know that the function is a diffeomorphism, we don't need to prove it. We can directly use the fact that there is a continuous inverse. As I said, this is what it feels like to me, I may be wrong.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you very much for your answer!